# EditText уходит под клавиатуру

Tags: android, android-edittext

На двух устройствах работает нормально. но на samsung s4 black edition(взломанный) `EditText` уходит под клавиатуру. по нажатию EText сперва ET поднимается вверх. после ввода первого символа Edettext уходит под клавиатуру. Если убрать в xml файле  android:gravity проблем нет.  но мне надо текст выравнивать по центру.

В манифесте    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"

Comment: Покажите xml в которой лежит EdetText. А можно еще и скриншот как оно выглядит без клавиатуры.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4789886/1159507) пишут что это баг, проявляется если использовать fullscreen activity, чтобы убрать status bar. Варианты решения - обернуть весь лайут в 
`ScrollView` или использовать `adjustResize` вместо `adjustPan`